# List.add() Class Expected

Tags: java, list

I'm taking a Java class in College. My instructor is actually a teacher for languages derived from C, so she can't figure out what's going on with this piece of code. I read on this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html that I could use the syntax "list[].add(int index, element)" to add specific objects or calculations into specific indexes, which reduced the amount of coding needed. The program I'm looking to create is a random stat generator for D&D, for practice. The method giving the error is below:

//StatGenrator is used with ActionListener

```
private String StatGenerator ()
{
        int finalStat;
        String returnStat;

        //Creates an empty list.
        int[] nums={};

        //Adds a random number from 1-6 to each list element.
        for (int i; i > 4; i++)
            nums[].add(i, dice.random(6)+1); //Marks 'add' with "error: class expected"

        //Sorts the list by decending order, then drops the
        //lowest number by adding the three highest numbers 
        //in the list.            
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        finalStat = nums[1] + nums[2] + nums[3]; 

        //Converts the integer into a string to set into a 
        //texbox.
        returnStat = finalStat.toString();
        return returnStat;
}
```

My end goal is to use some kind of sorted list or method of removing the lowest value in a set. The point of this method is to generate 4 random numbers from 1-6, then drop the lowest and add the three highest together. The final number is going to be the text of a textbox, so it is converted to a string and returned. The remainder of the code works correctly, I am only having trouble with this method.

If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears. I've researched a bit and found something about using ArrayList to make a new List object, but I'm not sure on the syntax for it. As a final note, I tried looking for this syntax in another question, but I couldn't find it anywhere on stackoverflow. Apologies if I missed something, somewhere.

Comment: Nowhere in that link does it say you can do `list[].add...`

Comment: `int[] nums={};` creates and empty Array not a list

Comment: Maybe she shouldn't be teaching Java if she doesn't know it. You would probably be better off using a List<Integer>.

Comment: I'm just now learning the intricacies of the java language, so I assumed that I could use an Array like a list. I'll take your comments into consideration when I work with Arrays in the future.

Comment: @Estel - never assume... :)  (Especially if you're learning, and especially when it comes to programming languages.  It's important to be precise.)

Comment: @ChadNC She's a great teacher, the College just decided it would save money if she teached it as opposed to hiring a dedicated Java instructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are fixed size, so you need to allocate space for all the slots at the start. Then to put numbers into the array assign to `nums[i]`. No add() method needed.

```
int[] nums = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    nums[i] = dice.random(6) + 1;

Arrays.sort(nums);
finalStat = nums[1] + nums[2] + nums[3];
```

---

Alternatively, if you really want a dynamically-sized array, use an ArrayList. An ArrayList can grow and shrink.

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    nums.add(dice.random(6) + 1);

Collections.sort(nums);
finalStat = nums.get(1) + nums.get(2) + nums.get(3);
```

Notice how different the syntax is due to ArrayList being a class rather than a built-in type.

Comment: Sometimes the best answers are the most simple. I facepalm at myself. Thank you very much.

Comment: The array will only ever have 4 elements when it's processed. A fixed-size array will work very nicely, now that I understand the concept a little better.

Answer (score 4):

'int nums[]' is not a List, it's an array.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
```

creates a new ArrayList for example.

You can access Elements in the list directly with the following Syntax :

```
intList.get(0); // Get the first Element
```

You can sort Lists with the Collections class :

```
Collections.sort(intList);
```

Here are some informations about Collections in Java : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: It's that simple? The article I looked at before made it seem much more complicated. Thanks very much.

Comment: Just two additions : If you use Java 6 or older you need the following Syntax : `List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` and note that Integer is not the same as int!

Answer (score 2):

> nums[].add(i, dice.random(6)+1); //Marks 'add' with "error: class
>   expected"

You are trying to use `add` on an array. List is a dynamic array, but that doesn't mean that **array == List**.  you should use List instead.

```
 List<Integer> nums=new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Adds a random number from 1-6 to each list element.
for (int i; i > 4; i++)
    nums.add(i, dice.random(6)+1);
```

Comment: also I would expect the last line to start with `nums.add(...`, and not `nums[].add(`.  *Hopefully* the latter is a compiler error, else it's probably doing something confusing...

Comment: oops, it was copy/paste mistake. @sotirious Delimanolis thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Aye, the brackets were a mistake on my part. I had changed it, thinking that may have been the error. I left it on there by accident when I copy/pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing arrays and lists.

Have a look at the tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html